# How to filter a requests response based on the values in a list?

Tags: python, list, python-requests, tuples

I want to filter a requests output based on the models mentioned in `my_list`. So I actually want if model is mentioned in `my_list` get that output. Below is my code:

```
import requests

my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

url = 'https://w3schools.com/python/demopage.php'

bug = requests.get(url, params = (("model", [my_list])))

print(bug)
```

**This is my current output:**

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Any slim ideas to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import requests

my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

url = 'https://w3schools.com/python/demopage.php'

bug = requests.get(url, params={"model": my_list})

print(bug)
```

Comment: I tried this: `params = (
    {'$filter': my_list},
    {'$select': 'ResultId, CompletedOn, EnteredValue, EnteredOn, TextValue\n'},
    {'$count': 'true'},
    {'$expand': 'Test($expand=Sample($select=SampleId)), Test($expand=TestType($select=Name)), Test($select=SpecificationStatus), ResultType($select=Name), Unit($select=Name)\n'},
)`  and I got this back: `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`

Comment: You should get rid of parenthesis, params take a dictionary, not a tuple, a url like this will generated in the given answer:
`https://w3schools.com/python/demopage.php?model=[1,2,3,4,5]`
if you were to add another parameter like this:
`params={"model": my_list, "param2" : "my_param2"}`

You'll get this:
`https://w3schools.com/python/demopage.php?model=[1,2,3,4,5]&param2=my_param2`

Comment: @sergenp abi can we chat in something so I can explain to you?